# Rxjs stream behaves differently in test vs app

Tags: unit-testing, rxjs

I've got a simple component in the app making pseudo randomization of numbers. Each number position is taken from a different array iterated in an infinite loop with different iteration frequency. Code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-marble-tests-evwezt?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Interval time is set this way that on one hundred position changes tens position is changed three times and units 6 times. Running the app everything works as expected, but running the test, the same component behaves differently and generates wrong numbers than expected. Any ideas how to force a test to execute code the same way (marble is not the case, jasmine.clock and tick gives the same result)? Because seems to me, that in the app component works correctly, what confirms also this pure rxjs [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ayci4n).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow you, because all example code is linked in topic description.